# Activate the main camera while developing a Simple Camera app on Visual Studio 13 for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am a beginner and a student who is just introduced to the WP app development, and as for my first project, I decided to build a very simple camera app, with limited functionality. So far, I have my GUI ready, and my question is, how do I activate the main camera ( or switch between the front and the main cameras )? This is my code on the `OnNavigatedTo` section which opens up the front camera of the phone.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += BackButtonPress;

    media = new MediaCapture();

    await media.InitializeAsync();

    ////rotation

    media.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise270Degrees);

    // VideoRotation previewRotation = media.GetPreviewRotation();

    ////start Capture preview

    ////capturePreview is a CaptureElement defined in XAML.

    this.capPrev.Source = media;

    await media.StartPreviewAsync();
}
```

I might be missing a simple line of code, that I am not aware of. My app right now launches the front camera instead of the main. What should I do to switch to the main camera? (I have the switch button ready on the appbar, which currently does nothing).
Thank you

Comment: Once I've written [a simple post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/) which may help a little. Note also that it's not a good idea to put this code in `OnNavigatedTo`.

Comment: thanks and the article is nice! gave me an idea that the ffc is the default one. We beginners need small but important infos like these hehe. Anyway, I used the code on OnNavigatedTo because my camera launches when the user button clicks/taps a button on the other page, the main page. To make you more clear, users tap the 'Capture Photo' button on the home page, and the camera launches on the other pages, so I thought adding it on the onNavigatedTo will directly launch the camera. Is there an other way around?

Comment: [Loaded event might be a better choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto) here. Whatch out that also you will have to handle suspending/resuming (if you are wrtiing for WinRT).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

First I didn't get what you wrote in your code.

Here is the [Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/AdvancedCamera-ba47da27/sourcecode?fileId=119486&pathId=1696910451) & [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx) for your requirement
Still if you face any issue please be specify your problem.

Best of luck

Comment: im sorry for the incomplete set of codes, I meant to let readers know that, that is what is what I wrote on the OnNavigatedTo section, ie what the app does when the page is loaded, and that set of codes activate the front camera when loaded. Like I stated, I am looking to try and activate the main camera when the app loads. Thank you for the reply and the links, I am working on Visual Studio Express 2013 and most samples and tutorials I have found yet are on VS 2012, which is a bit different and have confused me even more.

Comment: Look at the Sample I posted in my answer :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I replied to you without reading the updated comment. Thank you once again, i'm going through the sample's code and will ask if I stumble across something I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate cameras using below given line.

```
var set = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
set.VideoDeviceId = devices[0].Id;   // You should choose any value from devices collection

media = new MediaCapture();
await media.InitializeAsync(set);
```

Don't forget to dispose camera in `OnNavigatedFrom` event.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    await _camCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
    media.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a toggle camera button on my GUI, and I need to generate a click event which toggles cameras, back/front or vice versa. As for the " set.VideoDeviceId = devices[0].Id;   // You should choose any value from devices collection "
do I replace the 0 with 2? Or just 1? And, this might be stupid, but why does the app start up with the front facing camera instead of the main? Is there a specific line im missing? THank you

Comment: No, you not missing any code. Front camera is default. You need to check what values `devices` variable has. I think it will have two values so 0th value will be for front camera & other for rear. To switch camera you have re-initialize camera with corresponding settings.